# How can I make tabularx break lines rather than hypenate?

Tags: tables, hyphenation, badness

I tables, especially in the header row, I prefer line breaks rather than hyphenating words.

Can I make LaTeX prefer line breaks to hyphenation?

### Minimal Example

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
\hline
abcefghijkl bananarama & abcefghijkl bananarama & abcefghijkl bananarama \\\hline
\end{tabularx}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

but I would rather like "bananarama" to be one word on a new line

Comment: `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X` instead of just `X`

Comment: @egreg Nice! Should I post it as a community answer or do you want to do make the comment an answer? Could you explain what exactly this does?